# Are there any Haskell libraries for integrating complex functions?

Tags: haskell, numerical-methods, complex-numbers, integral

1. How to numerically integrate complex, complex-valued functions in Haskell?
2. Are there any existing libraries for it? [numeric-tools](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numeric-tools) operates only on reals.

I am aware that on complex plane there's only line integrals, so the interface I am interested in is something like this:

```
i = integrate f x a b precision
```

to calculate integral along straight line from `a` to `b` of function `f` on point `x`.
`i`, `x`, `a`, `b` are all of `Complex Double` or better `Num a => Complex a` type.

Please... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make something like this yourself. Suppose you have a function `realIntegrate` of type  `(Double -> Double) -> (Double,Double) -> Double`, taking a function and a tuple containing the lower and upper bounds, returning the result to some fixed precision. You could define `realIntegrate f (lo,hi) = quadRomberg defQuad (lo,hi) f` using numeric-tools, for example.

Then we can make your desired function as follows - I'm ignoring the precision for now (and I don't understand what your `x` parameter is for!):

```
integrate :: (Complex Double -> Complex Double) -> Complex Double -> Complex Double -> Complex Double
integrate f a b = r :+ i where
    r = realIntegrate realF (0,1)
    i = realIntegrate imagF (0,1)
    realF t = realPart (f (interpolate t)) -- or realF = realPart . f . interpolate
    imagF t = imagPart (f (interpolate t))
    interpolate t = a + (t :+ 0) * (b - a)
```

So we express the path from `a` to `b` as a function on the real interval from 0 to 1 by linear interpolation, take the value of `f` along that path, integrate the real and imaginary parts separately (I don't know if this can give numerically badly behaving results, though) and reassemble them into the final answer.

I haven't tested this code as I don't have numeric-tools installed, but at least it typechecks :-)

Comment: You still need to multiply the result with `b - a`, but then it should work correctly.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Good point! It's been ages since I last did a change of variables that wasn't an alpha renaming...

Comment: Oh, wow. Your anwser pointed me at the crucial difference in understanding what "integration" means. :( I'm not really interested in the limit of partial sums on the line AB, but in the value of the `F(x)` given the `f(x)` instead (x being complex number of course). Hence the `x` argument in my proposed function declaration. Thank you very much for the solution! I'm kinda confused now, though, whether I should open another question or edit this one instead...

Comment: OK, I'll accept your excellent answer and ask another question. :)