# How to numerically calculate value of complex function given derivative of this function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, complex-numbers, integral, derivative

Given:

1. Haskell
2. Complex-valued function `df/dz` defined on complex plane `U` (let's say `z` is a `Complex Double`).
3. Point `z1` from the `U` on which `df/dz` is defined.

Question:

How to get value of function `f(z)` for which `df/dz` is a derivative, in point `z1`?
I. e. how to restore value of original function given only it's derivative, assuming complex plane?

---

This question is somewhat related to [my previous question about calculating integrals of complex functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17038693/647199), but they are about different things. Here I am interested not in calculating some scalar value, but in finding the origin function given it's derivative. It's essentially calculating the indefinite integral of this derivative.

Comment: You can't do that.  The derivative of a function doesn't uniquely determine the function.  The is the same as doing integration, so there'll be at least a constant you don't know.

Comment: Do you want a numerical or symbolic approach?  I.e. is `df/dz` always some expression involving plus, times, exponents, sine, ... etc., or do you have e.g. some numerical data?  Unfortunately, both cases are rather hard...

Comment: OMG, @augustss thank you so much, I totally don't know how I would forget this basic math problem... (facepalm) However, I still need to solve this problem at least partially. I can infer missing _C_ using some additional constraints to original problem (so initial data will be not just `df/dz` but also some set of constraints).

Comment: @luqui I need just a numerical solution, even if analytical representation of origin function would be absolutely great, just a value of `f(x)` is enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

([Runge–Kutta in Haskell](http://stochastix.wordpress.com/2012/06/29/runge-kutta-in-haskell/))

You can use some numeric solver like [Runge-Kutta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods)

```
-- define 4th order Runge-Kutta map (RK4) 
rk4 :: Floating a => (a -> a) -> a -> a -> a
rk4 f h x = x + (1/6) * (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)
            where k1 = h * f (x)
                  k2 = h * f (x + 0.5*k1)
                  k3 = h * f (x + 0.5*k2)
                  k4 = h * f (x + k3)
```

in that case function signature is `Floating` but you can use `RealFloat` instead (you can use runge-kutta in complex).

Complete example:

```
Prelude> import Data.Complex
Prelude Data.Complex> let rk4 f h x = x + (1/6) * (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4) where {k1 = h * f(x);k2 = h * f (x + 0.5*k1);k3 = h * f (x + 0.5*k2);k4 = h * f (x + k3)}
Prelude Data.Complex> let f z = 2 * z
Prelude Data.Complex> rk4 f (0.1 :+ 0.2) (0.3 :+ 1.2)
(-0.2334199999999999) :+ 1.4925599999999999
Prelude Data.Complex>
```

On the other hand, @leftaroundabout suggest extend that behavior to [`VectorSpace`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector-space/0.8.6/doc/html/Data-VectorSpace.html#t%3aVectorSpace) (great! of course! :D )

Comment: In fact, it could be quite a lot more general than `Floating` yet, [`VectorSpace`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector-space/0.8.6/doc/html/Data-VectorSpace.html#t:VectorSpace) is what I'd go for.

Comment: I think I'll need a lot more math&haskell background to understand the necessity in `VectorSpace`, but nevertheless the Runge-Kutta solution using `RealFloat` seems to be what I want. :)

Comment: @hijarian: there's no _necessity_ to use `VectorSpace`, it just allows using the algorithm for much more complicated problems. (And the standard `RealFloat` types are instances of `VectorSpace` already, namely ℝ).

Comment: Why RK? Why not explicit Euler for example? For that matter RK4 may not be appropriate depending on your application.

Comment: @DominicSteinitz, yes you can use another one method :)